# Marionette Router Query String Parameters In URL Fragment Routes

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I'm working on a project that requires that most UI state is reproducible via URL. In a traditional (server-side) app, I could use both URL parameters like:

/resources/:id

*and* unordered optional query string parameters, like:

/resources/:id?page=5&sort=date

Is there an idiomatic way to achieve this with Backbone/Marionette routing? I don't want to have to configure routes for every possible combination of parameters.

The fact that I don't see this addressed much makes me think I may be barking up the wrong tree, approach-wise, but I do think being able to represent as much UI state as possible in the URL is pretty important to a lot of projects.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the best option is the now-orphaned [backbone-query-parameters](https://github.com/jhudson8/backbone-query-parameters) project.

It supports routes exactly in the form I'm looking for:

`#resources/:id?flag=true`

Answer (score 0):

URL parameters are not really enforced by Backbone/Marionette. One possible reason is that URL parameters are not SEO friendly.

Instead, you can configure optional URL fragments which will work pretty much like URL parameters, this way:

```
/resources/:id(/page/:page)(/sort/:sort)
```

If you do this way, the only gotcha here is that this sequence of "parameters" need to be ordered.

HOWEVER if you need it to be unordered, you can simply use Regular Expressions with `router.route()` method inside your `initialize`, as explained in [Router#route](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route)